# Dividing numbers without getting garbage numbers

Tags: binary, precision, division

I'm writing a program to convert fractional numbers to 64 bit floating point binary. Everything is working fine, but there is a part of my code where I need to "move the comma" of a binary (for example, 111.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000), so I divide the binary by ten (three times, in this case). Ideally, I would get **1.110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.** However, I obtain **1.110000000000000000013010426069826053208089433610439**. How can I correct this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

***You can't.***

**111.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000** and **1.110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000** are completely different when expressed in binary, insomuch as precision.

Use a fixed point decimal.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? If C++, you should be using `#include <decimal/decimal>`.

Comment: I'm using C. Error: file not found.

Answer (score 0):

**It is unpossible**, as seen in

[What every programmer should know about floating point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

---

The problem lies in the inability of modern computers to correctly use absolute precision when using `double`s.

`double`s use relative accuracy, which means that relatively to the order or magnitude your number will be displayed more or less accurate. Some numbers may even be displayed correctly while others suffer from minor inaccuracies, such as `1/3`, which is actually `0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125` but as it's relative error is small enough it is negligible.